# What to call it when a clock no longer runs

Tags: questions

What do you say when your clock or watch is stuck at a time and doesn't continue?

I know about fast and slow but my question is about when it doesn't move at all

Comment: Your clock is **out of order** or **broken**

Comment: "Even a stopped clock is right twice a day."  That saying goes back to 1880 and is still current, in spite of the digital age.

Answer (score 2):

You say the clock is **stopped**.